# Select tag isn't filled with data with jquery on ASP.Net if i remove an Alert()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The following code runs on the page load event.
If the ExCountries (asp:HiddenField) has value, then the CountriesListTo (Select Tag) will be filled (Appended) with data (Countries in my case).
For example ExCountries has the following value:
`"753,768,769,776,780,784,787,800,801,805,806,814"`
which is all the Countries IDs i want to exclude from the list.
The webservice function setExCountriesById returns a list of Counties (id, CountryGR).
When BindExCountriesbyId is called, CountriesListTo is filled, only if i leave the alert("appending").
If i remove the alert, then the Select tag isn't filled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var alertOnLoadMsg = "";
    var url1 = window.location.href.split('/');
    var baseUrl = url1[0] + '//' + url1[2];
    var countControls;
    var countGroupControls;

    countControls = 1;

    if ($("#ExCountries").val() != "") {
        var arr = new Array();
        arr = $("#ExCountries").val();
        AddExCountries(arr, countControls);
    }
    else {
        $("#ExCountries").val("");
    }

    function AddExCountries(vals, countControls) {
        var valsArray = vals.split(",");
    //    alert(valsArray);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + "/webservices/CargoData.asmx/setExCountriesById",
                data: "{vals: " + JSON.stringify(valsArray) + "}",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    BindExCountriesbyId(result.d, countControls);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                }


            });
        });

    }

    function BindExCountriesbyId(result, num) {
        var arr = new Array();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("appending");
            $("#CountriesListTo" + num).blur();
            $("#CountriesListTo" + num).empty();
            $.each(result, function () {
                $("#CountriesListTo" + num).append($("<option></option>").val(this.id).html(this.CountryGR));
            });
            $("#CountriesListTo" + num).trigger("liszt:updated");
            $("#CountriesListTo" + num).blur();

            $('#CountriesListTo' + num + ' option').each(function (i) {
                arr.push($(this).val());
            });
        });

        $("#ExCountries").val(arr);

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following changes :

I have added delay for success function call:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var alertOnLoadMsg = "";
        var url1 = window.location.href.split('/');
        var baseUrl = url1[0] + '//' + url1[2];
        var countControls;
        var countGroupControls;

        countControls = 1;

        if ($("#ExCountries").val() != "") {
            var arr = new Array();
            arr = $("#ExCountries").val();
            AddExCountries(arr, countControls);
        }
        else {
            $("#ExCountries").val("");
        }

        function AddExCountries(vals, countControls) {
            var valsArray = vals.split(",");
        //    alert(valsArray);
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl + "/webservices/CargoData.asmx/setExCountriesById",
                    data: "{vals: " + JSON.stringify(valsArray) + "}",
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                           BindExCountriesbyId(result.d, countControls);}, 1000);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
                    }


                });
            });

        }

        function BindExCountriesbyId(result, num) {
            var arr = new Array();

            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("appending");
                $("#CountriesListTo" + num).blur();
                $("#CountriesListTo" + num).empty();
                $.each(result, function () {
                    $("#CountriesListTo" + num).append($("<option></option>").val(this.id).html(this.CountryGR));
                });
                $("#CountriesListTo" + num).trigger("liszt:updated");
                $("#CountriesListTo" + num).blur();

                $('#CountriesListTo' + num + ' option').each(function (i) {
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                });
            });

            $("#ExCountries").val(arr);

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
It has a small latency from the timeout but it's ok for the time.